# Inherited props aren't being changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I created a prop in App.js "score". It is inherited by Gameboard.js and then to Endscene.js. Now when the prop is updated "score" isn't changing in Gameboard.js. I also inherit "score" from App.js to Header.js and there it updated properly. I know it works asynchronous and it doesn't updated directly. But even if I wait a minute, nothing changes. Score is still 0 in Gameboard.

I created "score" in App.js and inherit to Gameboard.js

```
function App() {
  const [textBox, setTextBox] = useState('Welcome To The Party')
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
```

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header text={textBox} score={score} timer={timer} decreaseTimer={decreaseTimer} timerActive={timerActive}/>
      <Gameboard 
      setText={setText} 
      increaseScore={increaseScore} 
      score={score}
      resetScore={resetScore} 
      timer={timer} 
      toggleTimer={toggleTimer}
      resetTimer={resetTimer}
      /> 
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
```

Here I inherit it to Endscript.js, where it is empty. Even when I increase it. But it works properly in Header.js

```
    function handleEndScene() {
        const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
        gameboard.style.backgroundImage = ('')
        ReactDOM.render( 
            <EndScene 
            handleButton={handleButton}
            score={props.score}
            />, gameboard
        )

      
    }
```

Now the funny part of the whole thing is.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setScore(props.score);
        console.log('Use Effect')
        console.log(props.score)
    }, [props.score])
```

Console.log(props.score) has the current value. For example one when I'm increase it. But it isn't update the score function inside the Gameboard.js(which I deleted because it leads to nothing). Nevertheless, the console.log worked well. But just in that function

Full code below

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Header from './Components/Header'
import Footer from './Components/Footer'
import Gameboard from './Components/Gameboard';

function App() {
  const [textBox, setTextBox] = useState('Welcome To The Party')
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30)
  const [timerActive, setTimerActive] = useState(false)


  const setText = (text) => {
    setTextBox(text)
  }

  const increaseScore = () => {
    setScore(score + 1)
  }

  const resetScore = () => {
    setScore(0)
  }

  const decreaseTimer = () => {
    setTimer(timer - 1)
  }

  const toggleTimer = () => {
    setTimerActive(prevTimerActive => !prevTimerActive);
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTimer(30)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header text={textBox} score={score} timer={timer} decreaseTimer={decreaseTimer} timerActive={timerActive}/>
      <Gameboard 
      setText={setText} 
      increaseScore={increaseScore} 
      score={score}
      resetScore={resetScore} 
      timer={timer} 
      toggleTimer={toggleTimer}
      resetTimer={resetTimer}
      /> 
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Gamebard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Character from './Character'
import EndScene from './EndScene'
import '../Styles/Gameboard.css'


export default function Gameboard(props) {
    const [charList, setCharList] = useState([])
    const [mapList, setMapList] = useState([])
    const [characterAlive, setCharacterAlive] = useState([])
    const [roundActive, setRoundActive] = useState(false)
    // const [score, setScore] = useState(0)

 
    useEffect(() => {
        buildCharList()
        buildMapList()
    }, [])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     setScore(props.score);
    //     console.log('Use Effect')
    //     console.log(props.score)
    // }, [props.score])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.timer === 0 && roundActive) handleEndScene()
    }, [props.timer])

    function handleEndScene() {
        const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
        gameboard.style.backgroundImage = ('')
        ReactDOM.render( 
            <EndScene 
            handleButton={handleButton}
            score={props.score}
            />, gameboard
        )

      
    }

    const resetCharacterAlive = () => {
        const newArray = []
        setCharacterAlive(newArray)
    }

    function handleEndRound() {
        if (characterAlive.length === charList.length) {
          
          // Update text and score
          props.setText('You Found All')
          props.increaseScore()

          //Update round/ reset data
            setRoundActive(false)
            props.toggleTimer()

          // Display select buttons
          const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
          const buttonGroup = () => (
                <>
                    <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
                    <button onClick={handleEndScene} className='leaveGameBtn btn btn-danger position-absolute'>Leave Game</button>
                </>
          )
          ReactDOM.render(buttonGroup(), gameboard)
        }
      }
      

    function buildMapList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.jpg/)) 
        setMapList(images);
    }

    function buildCharList() {
        function importAll(r) {
            return r.keys().map(r);
        }
        const images = importAll(require.context('../Assets/', true, /\.png/))
        setCharList(images);
    }

    function handleSetupGameboard() {
        const map = mapList.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)[0]
        const gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard')
        gameboard.style.backgroundImage = `url(${map})`


        const gameboardRect = gameboard.getBoundingClientRect()
        const charWidth = 70
        const charHeight = 70
        const maxX = gameboardRect.width - charWidth 
        const maxY = gameboardRect.height - charHeight

        const newCharList = charList.slice().sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        const charElements = newCharList.map((char, index) => {
            const xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX  + 1))   
            const yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY  + 1))
            return [
                <Character
                setText={props.setText}
                src={char}
                  style={{
                    left: `${xPos}px`,
                    top: `${yPos - (index * charHeight)}px`,
                  }}
                  key = {index}
                  onClick={handleCharFound}
                ></Character>
            ];
        })

        ReactDOM.render(charElements, gameboard)

        props.setText('Find Waldo, Lady Waldo and Wizard')
    }

    function handleCharFound(event) {
        if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
            const newCharacterAlive = characterAlive
            newCharacterAlive.push(event.target.src)
            setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
        }
        // if (!characterAlive.includes(event.target.src)) {
        //     const newCharacterAlive = [...characterAlive, event.target.src];
        //     setCharacterAlive(newCharacterAlive);
        //     console.log(newCharacterAlive)
        // }
        handleEndRound()
        console.log(`Char:${charList.length}, Alive:${characterAlive.length}`)    
    }

    function handleButton() {
        resetCharacterAlive()
        setRoundActive(true)
        handleSetupGameboard()
        props.resetScore()
        props.resetTimer()
        props.toggleTimer()
    }

        return (
        <div  className='gameBoardDiv'>
            <div id='gameboard'>
                <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
           </div>
        </div>
        )
}
```

EndScene.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import '../Styles/EndScene.css'
import { ref, set, get, child } from 'firebase/database';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';
import { database } from '../Components/Firebase'; 


 
export default function EndScene(props) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [highScores, setHighScores] = useState([]);

    function writeUserData(name, score) {
        set(ref(database, 'users/' + v4()), {
          username: name,
          score: score,
        });
    }

    function readDataBase() {
        const dbRef = ref(database);
        get(child(dbRef, `users/`)).then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            setHighScores(Object.entries(snapshot.val()))
          } else {
            console.log("No data available");
          }
          setIsLoading(false)
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          setIsLoading(false)
        });
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        readDataBase()
    }, []);
    
    function uploadUsername() {
        const input = document.getElementById('userName')
        const text = input.value
        writeUserData(text, props.score)
        props.handleButton()
    }

    return (
        <div className='outerDiv'>
            <div className='endSceneDiv border p-4 bg-white rounded input-group shadow'>
                <h2>Highscore</h2>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div className='w-100 listDiv'>
                        <ul className="highScore list-group w-100">
                            {highScores.map(([key, entry]) => (
                            <li key={key} className="list-group-item">
                                {entry.username}: {entry.score}
                            </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 
                )}
                <input id='userName' type="text" className='form-control mt-3 w-100' placeholder='Enter your name'/>
                <div className='d-flex mt-3'>
                    <button onClick={uploadUsername} className='btn btn-success'>Save Score</button>
                    <button onClick={props.handleButton} className='btn btn-info mx-2'>New Game</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think every time you call `ReactDOM.render` you create a separate react tree that will not detect props changes. Maybe you wanted to use a [portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#rendering-a-modal-dialog-with-a-portal)

Comment: Can you provide the code of the EndScene component ?

Comment: I think I either pointed this out, or asked about it, on a previous question of yours, but *why* are you calling `ReactDOM.render` in a callback function? I think in almost 100% of the use cases you should be ***returning*** `EndScene` somewhere in your app to be rendered to the UI, not creating a new ReactTree.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad) said, the call of `ReactDOM.render` create a separate tree.

Basically, this means that nothing in the new tree will be hooked by a change of state from the `App` component (because it is rendered outside the current state). This is not the case for the `Header` component because it is rendered in the same tree.

So what can you do ?

The best solution to me is to not use the `ReactDOM.render` at all in this case, but to use conditional rendering inside the `Gameboard` component (with children components or directly inside `Gameboard`)

For example, you can create a state for `charElements`, set it in `handleSetupGameboard`, and display it in your template if it is set.

```
const [charElements, setCharElements] = useState();

// ...

function handleSetupGameboard() {
  // ...
        
  // Here you set the render value of `charElements`
  setCharElements(newCharList.map((char, index) => {
    const xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX  + 1))   
    const yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY  + 1))
    return [
      <Character
      setText={props.setText}
      src={char}
      style={{
        left: `${xPos}px`,
        top: `${yPos - (index * charHeight)}px`,
      }}
      key = {index}
      onClick={handleCharFound}
      />
    ];
  }));

  props.setText('Find Waldo, Lady Waldo and Wizard')
}
```

And the in the return of your component something like this :

```
<div  className='gameBoardDiv'>
  <div id='gameboard'>
  {!charElements && <button onClick={handleButton} className='startGameBtn btn btn-info position-absolute'>Start Game</button>
  {!!charElements && charElements}
  </div>
</div>
```

And you should do the same to display the `EndScene` component.

This is just a way of doing it, you can also use a boolean to show the board, or a step system to know what to display ('start', 'game' or 'endgame' for example)

Hope this help